# Dead Code error

Tags: java, dead-code

I'm getting a dead code error in this Java code snippet, using Eclipse:

```
public void rebirthAction() {
    Player p = new Player(null);
    Equipment e = new Equipment();
    Skills s = new Skills(null);
    if ((Equipment.SLOT_SHIELD == -1) && (Equipment.SLOT_WEAPON == -1) && (Equipment.SLOT_CHEST == -1) && (Equipment.SLOT_BOTTOMS == -1) && (Equipment.SLOT_AMULET == -1) && (Equipment.SLOT_BOOTS == -1) && (Equipment.SLOT_HELM == -1) && (Equipment.SLOT_GLOVES == -1))
        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
            p.getSkills().setLevel(i, 1);
            p.getSkills().setExperience(i, 0);
            //updateRequired = true;
            //appearanceUpdateRequired = true;
            s.getTotalLevel();
            s.getCombatLevel();
            Combat.calculateMaxHit(p);
            p.getSkills();
            rebirthCount++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting an answer that isn't and a comment.

Comment: Thanks Michael for adding a useful question text.

Answer (score 8):

The `if` statement only checks final static values from the Equipment class and the compiler detects, that this condition can never be `true` so the following lines are dead code (unreachable).